I am getting a error displaying omniscript on the community portal
The error is

Error: Definition for module "forceGenerated/omniScript_Contract___Amend___English___lightning___false___brand___ltr" was not found

It was displaying the form earlier and I changed some components on the page around and now it's not working. I then removed all of the components and added just the omniscript component and the error appeared.
I have looked online and it said to me to do the following:

Please make sure the OWD for those object is set to Public Read/Write.
The objects are as follows : Omni DataPack, Omni Data Transformation, Omni Electronic Signature Template, Omni Process, Omni Process Transient Data, OmniScript Saved Session, Omni UI Card

There is not much more information I could find on this issue and this has not worked any help would be appreciated

I'm experiencing the same issue, I have an omniscript that I created in one environment, it worked there, I deployed it to another with all of its relevant Datamappers and Flexcards but I'm now getting this error.
I performed all of the recomended soltuions and no luck as of yet.
Did you manage to find a solution to this?
